# How to get IBackgroundTaskInstance?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I need that in order to execute [XamlRenderingBackgroundTask.OnRun](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.xamlrenderingbackgroundtask.onrun.aspx) . But I'm actually asking the more general question here - how does one get the [`IBackgroundTaskInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br224797) for the current Task when one is needed?

Comment: Please don't just link to off-site code. Try to make your questions self-contained. And "this" has never been a good link text, not in 1995 and not in 2016. You also added the "C++" tag without any good reason.

Comment: You don't "get" it, you are *passed* it when the function gets called. *"The system calls this method when the associated background task has been triggered."*

Comment: @ChristianHackl The link is actually not needed for the question and is only to appease those who "must" have one. The "C++" tag is because that would be helpful as well, and was removed (before your comment) only to appease those who hate double language tags. But I guess "downvoters will downvote"...

Comment: @CodyGray So you're saying it's impossible to just create a Task and run this code? I must create a "Background Task" with a trigger and all? OK. Back to the drawing board. Thanks. You can transform that into an answer (assuming I understood you correctly).

Comment: Just for the sake of readers who might take devRicher's comment serious, C++ supports every object-oriented feature that C# does. An interface, for example, would be a class with only public pure virtual functions. That's all there is to it. C++ does not have a keyword for interfaces because it's not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are badly misunderstanding the purpose of the `OnRun` method. As [the linked documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.xamlrenderingbackgroundtask.onrun.aspx) states:

> The system calls this method when the associated background task has been triggered.

It is a `protected` method that is provided as part of the infrastructure. As such, it is called automatically by infrastructure code, and you (the client) are only supposed to override it for handling purposes.

You basically never call `OnRun` yourself, thus you never need to provide any of its parameters. Rather, you are *passed* a reference to an object that implements `IBackgroundTaskInstance` when the function gets called, which you can use in your implementation of the method's body in a derived class.